# Crash that occurs only in production environment during deployment at Expo 49

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, eas

It works well on both iOS and Android using the Expo Go app and "expo prebuild".
However, if you deploy after "eas build", the app crashes and does not run as shown below.

In the case of Android, when running a production build file using "eas build", the error "couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so" occurs and the app closes.

I checked the issue, but didn't find anything helpful to me.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25537

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.21",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "expo": "^49.0.23",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.3.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1303.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-markdown-display": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "swr": "^2.2.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.13",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.config.js

```
export default {
  expo: {
    name: "**",
    slug: "**",
    version: "3.2.0",
    scheme: "jhschool",
    icon: "./assets/icon.png",
    orientation: "portrait",
    userInterfaceStyle: "light",
    experiments: { tsconfigPaths: true },
    splash: {
      image: "./assets/splash.png",
      resizeMode: "contain",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: ["**/*"],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: "**",
      buildNumber: "3.2.0",
      infoPlist: {
        NSCameraUsageDescription: "You need scan to QR",
        CFBundleDevelopmentRegion: "ko",
      },
      config: {
        usesNonExemptEncryption: false,
      },
      associatedDomains: ["applinks:**"],
    },
    android: {
      package: "**",
      versionCode: 27,
      permissions: ["NOTIFICATIONS", "CAMERA"],
      adaptiveIcon: {
        backgroundImage: "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      },
      intentFilters: [
        {
          action: "VIEW",
          data: [
            {
              scheme: "https",
              host: "**",
              pathPrefix: "/view",
            },
          ],
          category: ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"],
          autoVerify: true, // required to work on newer android versions
        },
      ],
    },
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: "**",
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          icon: "./assets/icon.png",
          color: "#ffffff",
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
};
```

Android Error

```
2024-02-18 06:37:09.569 25753-25753 SoLoader                pid-25753                            E  couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so
                                                                                                        SoSource 0: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/lib/x86_64 flags = 0]
                                                                                                        SoSource 1: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = [/data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.x86_64.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86_64]]
                                                                                                        SoSource 2: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = [/data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86_64]]
                                                                                                        SoSource 3: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = [/data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.x86_64.apk!/lib/x86_64]]
                                                                                                        SoSource 4: com.facebook.soloader.DirectApkSoSource[root = [/data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86_64]]
                                                                                                        SoSource 5: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib64 flags = 2]
                                                                                                        SoSource 6: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib64 flags = 2]
                                                                                                        Native lib dir: /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/lib/x86_64
                                                                                                     result: 0
2024-02-18 06:37:09.682 25753-25774 ExpoModulesCore         **           I  ✅ AppContext was initialized
2024-02-18 06:37:09.715 25753-25774 unknown:ReactContext    **            W  initializeMessageQueueThreads() is called.
2024-02-18 06:37:09.727 25753-25771 Gralloc4                **            I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2024-02-18 06:37:09.738 25753-25771 OpenGLRenderer          **            E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (25753) for package ** ----------------------------
2024-02-18 06:37:10.231 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A  Cmdline: me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal
2024-02-18 06:37:10.231 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A  pid: 25753, tid: 25753, name: un.jhschoolmeal  >>> me.kimdohyun.jhschoolmeal <<<
2024-02-18 06:37:10.233 25753-25802 cr_LibraryLoader        **            I  Successfully loaded native library
2024-02-18 06:37:10.234 25753-25802 cr_CachingUmaRecorder   **            I  Flushed 8 samples from 8 histograms.
2024-02-18 06:37:10.234 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #00 pc 0000000000081213  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libreanimated.so (offset 0xd19000) (BuildId: 127d6c0fc17234beafeadb82d411dd8d65be8054)
2024-02-18 06:37:10.234 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #01 pc 0000000000098c04  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libreanimated.so (offset 0xd19000) (reanimated::Scheduler::triggerUI()+228) (BuildId: 127d6c0fc17234beafeadb82d411dd8d65be8054)
2024-02-18 06:37:10.235 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #02 pc 000000000009c911  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libreanimated.so (offset 0xd19000) (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::AndroidScheduler::*)(), &(reanimated::AndroidScheduler::triggerUI()), reanimated::AndroidScheduler, void>::dispatch(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>)+33) (BuildId: 127d6c0fc17234beafeadb82d411dd8d65be8054)
2024-02-18 06:37:10.235 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #03 pc 000000000009c884  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libreanimated.so (offset 0xd19000) (facebook::jni::detail::FunctionWrapper<void (*)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>), facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, void (*)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<reanimated::AndroidScheduler, facebook::jni::detail::BaseHybridClass>::JavaPart, facebook::jni::JObject, void>::_javaobject*>))+52) (BuildId: 127d6c0fc17234beafeadb82d411dd8d65be8054)
2024-02-18 06:37:10.235 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #04 pc 000000000009b8f0  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/split_config.x86_64.apk!libreanimated.so (offset 0xd19000) (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (reanimated::AndroidScheduler::*)(), &(reanimated::AndroidScheduler::triggerUI()), reanimated::AndroidScheduler, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+32) (BuildId: 127d6c0fc17234beafeadb82d411dd8d65be8054)
2024-02-18 06:37:10.236 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #07 pc 00000000004a6eb8  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/base.apk (com.swmansion.reanimated.Scheduler$1.run+28)
2024-02-18 06:37:10.237 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #09 pc 00000000004a6ef8  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/base.apk (com.swmansion.reanimated.Scheduler$2.runGuarded+12)
2024-02-18 06:37:10.238 25799-25799 DEBUG                   pid-25799                            A        #11 pc 000000000037807c  /data/app/~~3iUtArC3z6X3AWF9OwG-jA==/**-I4660khgXEmP98mnsVZSWQ==/base.apk (com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run+0)
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (25753) for package ** ----------------------------
```

IOS Error

```
오류  06:42:43.946165+0900    tccd    Requestor: TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.nsurlsessiond, pid=117, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond is not entitled to check access for accessor TCCDProcess: identifier=**, pid=51973, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29401AD7-72BE-4A20-AE9E-A7A65032B1FE/app.app/app
오류  06:42:43.972450+0900    SpringBoard Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 51973; sceneIdentity: com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default
오류  06:42:43.998714+0900    SpringBoard Ignoring update for invalidated scene: (FBSceneManager):sceneID:**-default
오류  06:42:44.013312+0900    symptomsd   COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle ** has nil supplied UUID, finds existing 8C005B27-DE58-3BE4-B1B6-FE884E357580
오류  06:44:18.491532+0900    tccd    Requestor: TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.nsurlsessiond, pid=117, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond is not entitled to check access for accessor TCCDProcess: identifier=**, pid=51989, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29401AD7-72BE-4A20-AE9E-A7A65032B1FE/app.app/app
오류  06:44:18.516489+0900    SpringBoard Scene FBSceneManager/sceneID:**-default update failed: <NSError: 0x28b0f1230; domain: FBSceneErrorDomain; code: 1 ("operation-failed"); "Scene update failed."> {
    NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x28b023c00; domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain; code: 3 ("OperationFailed"); "XPC error received on message reply handler">;
}
오류  06:44:18.516567+0900    SpringBoard Scene FBSceneManager/sceneID:**-default update failed: <NSError: 0x28b0fbf90; domain: FBSceneErrorDomain; code: 1 ("operation-failed"); "Scene update failed."> {
    NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x2830be280; domain: BSServiceConnectionErrorDomain; code: 3 ("OperationFailed"); "XPC error received on message reply handler">;
}
오류  06:44:18.517538+0900    SpringBoard Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 51989; sceneIdentity: com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default
오류  06:44:18.550419+0900    SpringBoard Ignoring update for invalidated scene: (FBSceneManager):sceneID:**-default
오류  06:44:18.563987+0900    symptomsd   COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle ** has nil supplied UUID, finds existing 8C005B27-DE58-3BE4-B1B6-FE884E357580
오류  06:44:18.565015+0900    symptomsd   COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle ** has nil supplied UUID, finds existing 8C005B27-DE58-3BE4-B1B6-FE884E357580
오류  06:44:36.792783+0900    tccd    Requestor: TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.nsurlsessiond, pid=117, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond is not entitled to check access for accessor TCCDProcess: identifier=**, pid=51990, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29401AD7-72BE-4A20-AE9E-A7A65032B1FE/app.app/app
오류  06:44:36.814224+0900    SpringBoard Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 51990; sceneIdentity: com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default
오류  06:44:36.867409+0900    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 34-14990-2386815 (target:[app<**(A7E14B0A-11CC-4E38-A0DE-8FA575E5248D)>:51990](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default))
오류  06:44:36.869945+0900    symptomsd   COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle ** has nil supplied UUID, finds existing 8C005B27-DE58-3BE4-B1B6-FE884E357580
오류  06:44:36.873975+0900    symptomsd   COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle ** has nil supplied UUID, finds existing 8C005B27-DE58-3BE4-B1B6-FE884E357580
오류  06:45:18.545274+0900    tccd    Requestor: TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.nsurlsessiond, pid=117, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond is not entitled to check access for accessor TCCDProcess: identifier=**, pid=51991, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29401AD7-72BE-4A20-AE9E-A7A65032B1FE/app.app/app
오류  06:45:18.568855+0900    SpringBoard Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 51991; sceneIdentity: com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default
오류  06:45:18.601229+0900    SpringBoard Ignoring update for invalidated scene: (FBSceneManager):sceneID:**-default
오류  06:45:18.626454+0900    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 34-14990-2386838 (target:[app<**(A7E14B0A-11CC-4E38-A0DE-8FA575E5248D)>:51991](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default))
오류  06:45:18.636034+0900    symptomsd   COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle ** has nil supplied UUID, finds existing 8C005B27-DE58-3BE4-B1B6-FE884E357580
오류  06:45:18.641839+0900    symptomsd   COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle ** has nil supplied UUID, finds existing 8C005B27-DE58-3BE4-B1B6-FE884E357580
오류  06:45:54.483172+0900    tccd    Requestor: TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.nsurlsessiond, pid=117, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond is not entitled to check access for accessor TCCDProcess: identifier=**, pid=52003, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29401AD7-72BE-4A20-AE9E-A7A65032B1FE/app.app/app
오류  06:45:54.483191+0900    tccd    Requestor: TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.nsurlsessiond, pid=117, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond is not entitled to check access for accessor TCCDProcess: identifier=**, pid=52003, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29401AD7-72BE-4A20-AE9E-A7A65032B1FE/app.app/app
오류  06:45:54.516021+0900    SpringBoard Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 52003; sceneIdentity: com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default
오류  06:45:54.516040+0900    SpringBoard Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 52003; sceneIdentity: com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default
오류  06:45:54.559575+0900    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 34-14990-2386948 (target:[app<**(A7E14B0A-11CC-4E38-A0DE-8FA575E5248D)>:52003](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default))
오류  06:45:54.559556+0900    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 34-14990-2386948 (target:[app<**(A7E14B0A-11CC-4E38-A0DE-8FA575E5248D)>:52003](UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3A**-default))
```

It all worked in the Expo Go and Prebuild development environments, but did not work in the built deployment environment.

Answer (score 0):

It has been confirmed that this error occurs because Expo Updates are enabled by default.

If you modify the app.config.js/app.json file as shown below, it will work fine in production.

app.json

```json
expo: {
   updates: {
      enabled: false
   }
}
```